# LabVIEW - adding text to a string control instead of rewriting it

Tags: string, controls, labview

I managed to place text in my string indicator but what i wish to know is how to add text to it without deleting the previous text. I tried searching the web and i couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reuse its value by using a local variable, and input in `concatenate strings`.

[image]

Comment: why? what i normally do is change it to indicator and just connect the line to it..

Comment: sure, but if you want to keep it as a control, you need a property node (or a local variable, it does the same job)

Comment: i don't want to keep it a control and btw. i cant find the `Str Refnum` function

Comment: So I don't get your question, why not just change to indicator?

Comment: I did changed it to an indicator but when i set the value it overwrites the old one, i want it to add it like this: `oldvalue , newvalue`

Comment: thanks, im sorry i am new, when i try to create a local veriable it only lets me choose between a `file` and a `path` i can't choose a string

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16696/discussion-between-charlesb-and-dan-barzilay)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Concatenate Strings` to add two different strings to a single one. Then you still can use the first string without any change.

[Sample from NI help](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361D-01/glang/concatenate_strings/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is not what i ment. for example lets say my string control currently has the srting `h` and now i want to add to that control the string `ello` and my result will be that the control will have the string `hello`. how can i do it?

Comment: @DanBarzilay what exactly do you mean with the string `h`? and the string `ello`?

Comment: it was just an example.. im trying to add a string to the current control string..

Comment: @DanBarzilay Didn't i just gave you the tool to add a 2nd string to the first? If that's not what you meant please explain more what you want.

Comment: ok i understand now i think, can this concatenate strings get an array and add the strings on that array into a single one?

Comment: @DanBarzilay just try it and then you see :)

Comment: I tryed, it's saying that it needs to be a string but the site says that it can be an array..

Comment: look at CharlesB answer. he put a nice picture in

Answer (score 2):

For an indicator or control, you can also use the `Append String` function as follows:
[image]

... and then wire the string you want to append to the input of that function:

[image]

The net result is the same as using the `Concatenate Strings` that others have mentioned, but is perhaps more elegant on account of not needing to wire in the original value on the block diagram.

Comment: Upvoted for highlighting a method I didn't know, but it would be worth checking whether using an invoke node like this forces a switch to the UI thread, which reads/writes to/from local variables and control/indicator terminals do not.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate strings lets you concatenate multiple strings, and arrays of strings.

The Append String method appears to only let you concatenate a single string to a string control. I'm guessing it is more efficient, and better to use inside a loop.